# Output of omegaSem not showing due to object not found

Tags: r, data-analysis

I'm folowing a tutorial to perform ω Mcdonald Omega and α Cronbach Alpha in R, in order to estimate reliability for a psychometric test. This is my first time using R. I usually work on SPSS for related tasks. I'm also using the "psych" package to do so. Here is the link of the tutorial:

http://personality-project.org/r/psych/HowTo/R_for_omega.pdf

So I'm already in the very last step of this tutorial, after suceeding in some steps and asking help in some others. I've checked in related questions and it
seems that this kind of issues are individualized and related to the previous statements done along the whole code. I'm also thinking that maybe this issue is related to a bug or to the packages that I'm using, but I'm not able to figure out why the analysis is failing.

So this is the actual code that im trying to execute:

´´

```
> omegaSem(r9,n.obs=500)
Error in is.data.frame(m) : object 'r9' not found
```

´´

Thank you for any suggestion you can give me to solve my problem.

Feel free to ask any usefull information to solve this issue. Just let me know

Edit: I just found over the help page (http://127.0.0.1:24019/library/psych/html/omega.html) of the package, the parameters and arguments of the statement that I'm trying to execute:

´´

```
omegaSem(m,nfactors=3,fm="minres",key=NULL,flip=TRUE,digits=2,title="Omega",
  sl=TRUE,labels=NULL, plot=TRUE,n.obs=NA,rotate="oblimin",
  Phi = NULL, option="equal",lavaan=TRUE,...)
```

´´

next, this page shows the details about each argument:

**
Arguments
m
A correlation matrix, or a data.frame/matrix of data, or (if Phi) is specified, an oblique factor pattern matrix

nfactors
Number of factors believed to be group factors

n.iter
How many replications to do in omega for bootstrapped estimates

fm
factor method (the default is minres) fm="pa" for principal axes, fm="minres" for a minimum residual (OLS) solution, fm="pc" for principal components (see note), or fm="ml" for maximum likelihood.

poly
should the correlation matrix be found using polychoric/tetrachoric or normal Pearson correlations

key
a vector of +/- 1s to specify the direction of scoring of items. The default is to assume all items are positively keyed, but if some items are reversed scored, then key should be specified.

flip
If flip is TRUE, then items are automatically flipped to have positive correlations on the general factor. Items that have been reversed are shown with a - sign.

p
probability of two tailed conference boundaries

digits
if specified, round the output to digits

title
Title for this analysis

main
main for this analysis (directSl)

cut
Loadings greater than cut are used in directSl

sl
If plotting the results, should the Schmid Leiman solution be shown or should the hierarchical solution be shown? (default sl=TRUE)

labels
If plotting, what labels should be applied to the variables? If not specified, will default to the column names.

plot
plot=TRUE (default) calls omega.diagram, plot =FALSE does not. If Rgraphviz is available, then omega.graph may be used separately.

n.obs
Number of observations - used for goodness of fit statistic

rotate
What rotation to apply? The default is oblimin, the alternatives include simplimax, Promax, cluster and target. target will rotate to an optional keys matrix (See target.rot)

Phi
If specified, then omega is found from the pattern matrix (m) and the factor intercorrelation matrix (Phi).

option
In the two factor case (not recommended), should the loadings be equal, emphasize the first factor, or emphasize the second factor. See in particular the option parameter in schmid for treating the case of two group factors.

covar
defaults to FALSE and the correlation matrix is found (standardized variables.) If TRUE, the do the calculations on the unstandardized variables and use covariances.

lavaan
if FALSE, will use John Fox's sem package to do the omegaSem. If TRUE, will use Yves Rosseel's lavaan package.

fit
The fitted object from lavaan or sem. For lavaan, this includes the correlation matrix and the variable names and thus m needs not be specified.
**
Allows additional parameters to be passed through to the factor routines.

**Now, I'm trying to identify or recognize the specific argument that is related to the r9 not found object that is not letting me perform my analysis.** It seems that the argument is the m one, to define the correlation matrix:

**m
A correlation matrix, or a data.frame/matrix of data, or (if Phi) is specified, an oblique factor pattern matrix**

I tried to remove or to replace that argument with a different one, but I dont have anymore information to realize what I have to put there to make the code work. Also I donet understand so well the matrix that they talk about in that specific parameter.

´´

omegaSem(n.obs=240,lavaan=TRUE)
Error in omega(m = m, nfactors = nfactors, fm = fm, key = key, flip = flip,  :
el argumento "m" está ausente, sin valor por omisión

> omegaSem(r1,n.obs=240,lavaan=TRUE)
> Error in is.data.frame(m) : objeto 'r1' no encontrado
> omegaSem(1,n.obs=240,lavaan=TRUE)
> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

´´

thank you again for all the guidance you can give me to solve this issue

--------------------------TENTATIVE SOLUTION------------------------------------

After reading some documentation I decided to e-mail Dr. William, the author of the psych package, and he concluded that there was a lack of information in the guide. So the solution is that you have to assign that r9 variable or anyone to an actual database, so in order to perform that omegaSem() function you have to assign that variable correctly. For example:

r9 <- Thurstone

## Thurstone is a database that comes with the psych package, so after that, you are able to get the expected output

You can also set:

r9 <- my.data

## to assign that variable to any database defined in my.data

In conclusion, the r9 <- Thurstone statement was missing in the documentation

Comment: Have you looked at the help page for `omegaSem` in whatever unnamed package it comes from? (You don't really expect us to page through that pdf to find out all the packages that have been loaded to the point where that code appears do you?)

Comment: Not at all. That was just to make you sure about the source of the actions that I'm performing. I'm not sure if the issue comes with the package or it is a syntax problem.

Comment: Well the error message doesn't suggest a syntax problem but rather that the data object is not available in the search path. So you have probably copied code from a source but failed to do all the prep work needed to make the require data-object.

Comment: well, thank you. I've looked into several websites trying to check this. It seems that the missing value is a correlation matrix. The strange thing is that in the tutorial doesnt say anything about create such matrix. I think that maybe one have to create that matrix first so the function can work, not really sure but I'm getting closer to the solution